# Apply procedural bump map to mesh (displace modifier)

Tags: mesh, displacement, shader-nodes, bump

I have a Shader with some nodes:
[image]

But I want to use the information of the Bump map in a Displace modifier to affect the mesh. I tried so many ways but none work..

My goal is to 3d Print my design that's why I need to mesh to be modified.

How can I go from bump map in shading to a displacement map to alter the mesh?

Thanks!

Comment: Your mesh needs to be subdivided enough, you need to be in Cycles, you need to go into Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement and choose Displacement and Bump, and you need to be in Rendered mode to see the result. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Also, you need a _Displacement Node_ (Rather than a Bump node) to connect to the the Displacement Output.  Connect the same texture you used for the Bump Node to the Height input of the Displacement Node. The scale of the displacement is also commonly reduced to 0.2 or so (for Procedural Textures).